# How do Vagabond opening hand size challenges interact with the skill "Duel, Standby!"?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

Some of the Vagabond challenges specify how large your opening hand is, from 1 to 3 cards. However, Téa Gardner's skill "Duel, Standby!" skill starts both players with 5 cards. How do these effects interact? Does one negate the other, or do you just end up starting with 1 extra card above the challenge specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Duel, Standby!](http://duellinks.gamea.co/c/ffatvfcp) skill doesn't start both players out with 5 cards - it gives each player one additional card

> Gives 1 more card in each player's starting hand.

So using this skill against the Vagabond with the "Opening Hand: X Card" Challenge will start you off with an extra card as normal